# Linux, can't include sys modules

Tags: c, linux, include, kernel, sys

When I try to include a sys module (for example `#include <sys/shm.h>`) i get the following error: No such file or directory. Can't find any working solution on internet.
The language used is C.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in detail

Comment: are you sure your gcc is installed correctly?

Comment: For what it's worth, on my Ubuntu Linux system, it's here:  `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/shm.h`

Comment: I think the library is correctly installed, how can I check it?

Comment: I replaced the include with: #include <linux/shm.h> and gives me no errors. Is the same thing?

Comment: But still... doesn't work, when I call a function I get the error "implicit delcaration of function"

Comment: You tagged your question with *kernel* tag. Are you trying to compile a kernel module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glibc` headers are surely not installed (you may have just installed `gcc` without `glibc` headers).

If you run Ubuntu/Debian, this command should solve your issue:

```
sudo apt-get install libc-dev
```

Note: `linux/shm.h` and `sys/shm.h` are not the same. `linux/shm.h` is provided by Linux kernel and is not intended to be used by *normal* developer.

Comment: I think I found out what the problem is.
The header I need is in: usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys
The folder in wich the complier searches the headers is: lib/modules/kernel_version/build/include , so I basically need to install the required libraries there. How can I do that?

Comment: `apt-get install libc-dev` should solve problem, isn't?

Comment: Sadly not. I think I've to be more specific. To include linux/kernel.h, in the makefile I wrote "make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules" . Now all the includes start from "/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/include" folder, in wich there isn't a sys directory.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you didn't specify you was trying to compile a kernel module.

User space libraries (and user space function) are not available in kernel. That's why you can't include user space headers. You have to develop only with functions provided by kernel.